# Handle Multiple Response Data with REST API

Tags: database, laravel, api

I have issue in handling json multiple data. I am not getting multiple data and if I use "array" then also it creates single record with null values in database.

The Backend code for saving data

```
{ 
       $pickup = new PickupData();

       $pickup->pickup_person = $request->pickup_person;

       $pickup->office_city = $request->office_city;

       $pickup->office_state = $request->office_state;

       $pickup->office_pincode = $request->office_pincode;

       $pickup->pickup_email = $request->pickup_email;

       $pickup->preferred_start_time = $request->preferred_start_time;

       $pickup->preferred_end_time = $request->preferred_end_time;

       $pickup->mobile = $request->mobile;

       $pickup_date = Carbon::parse($request->pickup_date)->format('d-m-Y');

       $pickup->pickup_date = $pickup_date;

       $saved = $pickup->save();
}
```

I need response like and it should be saved into database

```
[
  {
    "pickup_person":"SanPune6",
    "city":"pune",
    "office_address":"viman nagar",
    "office_city":"Pune",
    "office_state":"MH",
    "office_pincode":"121212",
    "pickup_email":"office@gmail.com",
    "preferred_start_time":"12:38:29",
    "preferred_end_time":"13:02:33",
    "mobile":"9090909090",
    "pickup_date":"12-04-2019"
  },
  {
    "pickup_person":"SanPune6",
    "city":"pune",
    "office_address":"viman nagar",
    "office_city":"Pune",
    "office_state":"MH",
    "office_pincode":"121212",
    "pickup_email":"office@gmail.com",
    "preferred_start_time":"12:38:29",
    "preferred_end_time":"13:02:33",
    "mobile":"9090909090",
    "pickup_date":"12-04-2019"
  }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. create resource sth like this

```
  php artisan make:resource PickupResourceCollection
```

2. create another resource sth like

```
  php artisan make:resource PickupResource
```

3. in your index method of PickupController do sth like this

```
use use App\Http\Resources\PickupResourceCollection;
  ...
  public function index()
  {
     $pickups = Pickup::all();
     return response()->json(new PickupResourceCollection($pickups),200);
  }
 ...
```

4. in PickupResourceCollection do sth like this

```
....
 public function toArray($request)
 {
     return [
         'data' => $this->collection->transform(function ($pickups) {
             return new PickupResource($pickups);
         })
     ];
 }
 ....
```

5. in PickupResource do sth like this

```
....
 public function toArray($request)
 {
    return [
       "pickup_person"       =>$this->pickup_person,
       "city"                =>$this->city,
       "office_address"      =>$this->office_address,
       "office_city"         =>$this->office_city,
       "office_state"        =>$this->office_state,
       "office_pincode"      =>$this->office_pincode,
       "pickup_email"        =>$this->pickup_email,
       "preferred_start_time"=>$this->preferred_start_time,
       "preferred_end_time"  =>$this->preferred_end_time,
       "mobile"              =>$this->mobile,
       "pickup_date"         =>"$this->pickup_date
   ];
 }
 ....
```

thats it :)

Comment: Thanx @Bimal,  But I want response like

[
  {
    "application_id": "1"
  },
  {
    "application_id": "2"
  }

Comment: I have followed all above steps but, not able to save that multiple records in database. why? can you explain please

Comment: Also, I response it is showing all data which is available in database table

Comment: @shree to save data in table use  PickupData::create($request->all()), then use above steps to retrieve  data, above steps will return data in [ { "application_id": "1" }, { "application_id": "2" }] format

Comment: Thanx.

I used same function for storing data. But, I need to store multiple data at a time.

Also, wants to pass data in [ { "application_id": "1" }, { "application_id": "2" }] format.

Comment: @shree hummm, you can use foreach loop to store array of objects to database at same time

Comment: Sorry @bimal. I am already using foreach, but getting trouble in that.

Can you please help me to resolve that. I have used this logic. What is being wrong in that?

 $pickupDetails = array([
                'application_id' => $request['application_id'],
        ]);
        
//        dd($pickupDetails);
        foreach ($pickupDetails as $pickups) {
            Pickup::create($pickups);
        }

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can save by as an array.

```
$pickup = PickupData::create($request->all()) // to save all request data
$pickup = PickupData::create($request->except(['var1', 'var2'])) // to save all request data except var1 & var2
```

`$pickup` will return only newly inserted row.

Answer (score 0):

```
$pickupDetails =          [
                             {
                                 "pickup_person":"SanPune6",
                                 "city":"pune",
                                 "office_address":"viman nagar",
                                 "office_city":"Pune",
                                 "office_state":"MH",
                                 "office_pincode":"121212",
                                 "pickup_email":"office@gmail.com",
                                 "preferred_start_time":"12:38:29",
                                 "preferred_end_time":"13:02:33",
                                 "mobile":"9090909090",
                                 "pickup_date":"12-04-2019"
                             },
                             {
                                 "pickup_person":"SanPune6",
                                 "city":"pune",
                                 "office_address":"viman nagar",
                                 "office_city":"Pune",
                                 "office_state":"MH",
                                 "office_pincode":"121212",
                                 "pickup_email":"office@gmail.com",
                                 "preferred_start_time":"12:38:29",
                                 "preferred_end_time":"13:02:33",
                                 "mobile":"9090909090",
                                 "pickup_date":"12-04-2019"
                             }
                         ];
         $pickupDetails = $request->all();     
         foreach($pickupDetails as $pickup){ 
             Pickup::create($pickup);  
         }
         return response()->json("success",200);
```

if it helps you upvote me :)